# Strightforward parsing json using ‏µC/OS-II

Tags: c, arrays, json, embedded, codewarrior

Can anyone help in writing a C parser (using Codewarrior) to parse the following file? I tried many C language json parser, but unfortunately didn't get the idea or they make it difficult.

```
[
[0,"Door1","Door1Drv","Calculator","Alarm"],
[1,"Door3","Door3Drv","Calculator","Alarm"],
[2,"Door2","Door2Drv","Calculator","Alarm"]]
```

Comment: What parsers have you tried so far? Have you seen [JSMN](http://zserge.com/jsmn.html)?

Comment: Please show us your previous effort. Either with parser or with straight forward own implementation.

Comment: If you are asking for a recommendation, then this is OT, or if you are expecting a solution then it is too broad; either way it is unclear what you expect, so three reasons to close already!  Details of RTOS and toolchain are largely irellevant; details of precise requirements and constraints are missing. It is also not known what you have tried already, or why it was unsatisfactory.

Comment: Do you want a parser that can handle just that fragment, or one that parses JSON in general?  If the former, then the fact that it is JSON is perhaps also irrelevant, since you could make it specific rather then generic.  The fragment seems incomplete to me ; is that all that needs parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For advance application, recommend to use [Frozen](https://github.com/cesanta/frozen). If your application has fix data format as shown above, see below for your ref.

Quite basic version look like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PRAM    4

struct param_t {
    int id;

    // FIXME: use pointer & malloc to allocate if possible
    char data[MAX_PRAM][30];
};

static int parse(const char *buff, int start, const int end,
    struct param_t *out)
{
    char *ptr = out->data[0];
    int state = 0;
    int index = 0;
    int param_index = 0;

    printf("\t> parse next record<%d:%d>\n", start, end);
    while((start < end) && (param_index < MAX_PRAM)) {
        char ch = buff[start];

        // printf("\t> state: %d, char '%c'\n", state, ch);
        switch (state) {
            case 0: // searching for start point
                if ((ch >= '0') && (ch <= '9')) {
                    out->id = ch - '0';
                    state++;
                }

                break;

            case 1: // parse number
                if ((ch < '0') || (ch > '9')) {
                    printf ("\t> number %d\n", out->id);

                    state++;
                    if (ch == '"')
                        state++;
                } else
                    out->id = (out->id * 10) + (ch - '0');
                break;

            case 2: // search string
                if (ch == '"') {
                    index = 0;
                    state++;
                }

                break;

            case 3: // get string
                if (ch == '"') { // finish one string, parse next one if need
                    ptr[index] = '\0';

                     printf ("\t> string '%s', length %d\n",
                        out->data[param_index], index);

                    param_index++;
                    ptr = out->data[param_index];
                    state--;
                } else
                    ptr[index++] = ch;

                break;

            default: // EOS - exit
                break;
        }

        start++;
    }

    return (param_index >= 4) ? start : 0;
}

//
// main entry
//
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int file = open("test.txt", 0 /* 0 ~ O_RDONLY in fcntl.h */ );

    if (file) {
        char buff[1024] = { 0 };
        struct param_t param = { 0 };
        int len = read(file, buff, 1024);
        int pos = 0;

        while((pos = parse(buff, pos, len, &param)) > 0) {
            printf ("\t%d\n", param.id);

            printf("[%4d] %d - %-10s | %-10s | %-15s | %-10s \n",
                pos, param.id, param.data[0], param.data[1], param.data[2],
                param.data[3]);
        }

        close(file);
    }
}
```

With input:

```
[[10,"Door0",

"Door0Drv","Calculator0","Alarm0"],

[15,"Door1","Door1Drv","Calculator1","Alarm1"],

[230,"Door2","Door2Drv","Calculator2",
    "Alarm2"]]
```

Output looks like:

```
        > number 10
        > string 'Door0', length 5
        > string 'Door0Drv', length 8
        > string 'Calculator0', length 11
        > string 'Alarm0', length 6
        10
[  49] 10 - Door0      | Door0Drv   | Calculator0     | Alarm0
        > number 15
        > string 'Door1', length 5
        > string 'Door1Drv', length 8
        > string 'Calculator1', length 11
        > string 'Alarm1', length 6
        15
[ 100] 15 - Door1      | Door1Drv   | Calculator1     | Alarm1
        > number 230
        > string 'Door2', length 5
        > string 'Door2Drv', length 8
        > string 'Calculator2', length 11
        > string 'Alarm2', length 6
        230
[ 158] 230 - Door2      | Door2Drv   | Calculator2     | Alarm2
```

Feel free to customize.

Comment: this is useful @sdao. 

Can you help if it is dynamic, actually I have seen many json parser and the comparisons but I didn't get the point yet. 


-    Codewarrior doesn't recognize fopen keyword.

 FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");